# Prove that if f is differentiable on $(a, b)$ and $f'$ is increasing, then $f$ is convex on $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> A function $f$ is called convex on an interval $[a, b]$ if, for any $x, y \in
> [a, b]$ and $t \in [0, 1]$ we have $f(tx + (1 − t)y) \leq tf(x) + (1 − t)f(y)$.

Would drawing a picture of this help in understanding this question conceptually and visually? The proof of this question requires the use of the mean value theorem. I am struggling to understand this real analysis question.

Comment: I think you mean $f''$ is positive, otherwise $x^3$ is a counter example

Comment: Sorry It is f' not f''.

Comment: Ok, makes sense then

Answer (score 0):

The image you should have is that if $f'$ is increasing then the tangent lines to the graph of $f$ will, if you look at points from left to right, will rotate counter-clockwisr, pointing ever higher and getting closer to become vertical. If $f$ was piecewise linear, then it would be shaped like a **V**, which is concave. This is actually the general idea.

Given $x<y$ and $t\in[0,1]$, the point $z=tx+(1-t)y$ is between $x$ and $y$, so the derivatives to the left of $z$ are smaller than the ones to the right. Use this with the mean value theorem on the intervals between $x$, $y$ and $z$. This use of the Mean Vale Theorem is a way to approximate $f$ by a piecewise linear map.

Comment: So it will essentially be a piecewise absolute value |x| graph with piece wise points on the left and right side of this graph

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes, that's the informal idea.

Answer (score 0):

If $x < z < y$, then by the mean value theorem there exists $\xi_1,\xi_2$ such that $x < \xi_1 < z < \xi_2 < y$ and

$$\tag{1}\frac{f(z) - f(x)}{z - x} = f'(\xi_1) \leqslant f'(\xi_2) = \frac{f(y) - f(z)}{y-z}$$

Note that $\leqslant$ can be replaced with $<$ if $f'$ is strictly increasing (leading to strict convexity).

Since $z$ is between $x$ and $y$, we have $t \in (0,1)$ such that $z = tx + (1-t)y$.

It follows that

$$\tag{2}z-x = (1-t)(y-x),$$ 
$$\tag{3} y-z = t(y-x)$$

I'll leave it to you to show using (1), (2) and (3) that

$$f(z) \leqslant tf(x) +(1-t)f(y),$$

proving convexity.

Comment: I am still having trouble proving these three conditions to show the convexitiy

Comment: (1) is just a statement of the mean value theorem and the fact that $f(\xi_1) \leqslant f(\xi_2)$ since $\xi_1 < \xi_2$ and you have the hypothesis that $f'$ is increasing.  For (2) we have $z = tx + (1-t)y \implies z -x = tx - x + (1-t)y = -(1-t)x + (1-t)y = (1-t)(y-x)$..

Comment: Could you please prove this for me I still do not follow. I get that you have to do this mean value theorem application for (1) (2) and (3) but I just can't construct it. It looks like you have proved (1) is that right?